# Mockito with Kotlin testing async failure

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

I'm trying to learn Mockito for my tests but when using Kotlin it's more complicated. I want to test a function in my presenter which when called is fetching a list of objects from the repository asynchronously and fires onSuccess/onError from a listener. After that the presenter tells the view to do whatever is needed according to the callback.

Here's the test code:

```
@Mock
lateinit var view: CategoriesActivityContract.View

@Mock
lateinit var repository: CategoriesRepository

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}

@Test
fun shouldPassCategoriesToView2() {
    `doAnswer`({
        it: InvocationOnMock? ->
        (it!!.arguments[0] as CategoriesRepository.OnGetCategoriesListener).onSuccess(DUMMY_CATEGORIES)
        null
    }).`when`(repository).getCategoriesAsync(any(CategoriesRepository.OnGetCategoriesListener::class.java))


    val presenter: CategoriesActivityPresenter = CategoriesActivityPresenter(repository)
    presenter.bindView(view)
    presenter.loadCategories()


    `verify`(view).displayCategories(DUMMY_CATEGORIES)
}
```

That's the tested code:

```
override fun loadCategories() {
    repository.getCategoriesAsync(object: CategoriesRepository.OnGetCategoriesListener {
        override fun onSuccess(categories: List<Category>) {
            if (!categories.isEmpty()) {
                view?.displayCategories(categories)
            } else {
                view?.displayNoCategoriesError()
            }
        }

        override fun onError(message: String?) {
            view?.displayNoCategoriesError()
        }
    })
}
```

And the test fails with this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: any(CategoriesRepository…riesListener::class.java) must not be null

at com.boyukliev.verseattack.ui.categories.CategoriesActivityPresenterTest.shouldPassCategoriesToView2(CategoriesActivityPresenterTest.kt:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.boyukliev.verseattack.ui.categories.CategoriesActivityPresenterTest.shouldPassCategoriesToView2(CategoriesActivityPresenterTest.kt:60)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.testFinished(DefaultInternalRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Mockito.any(Class<T>)` returns `null` ([[1]](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.java#L206), [[2]](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/util/Primitives.java#L59)), which is not accepted by the `getCategoriesAsync` method.
You can use the [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/) library which does 'not return null values' to overcome this problem.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the author of Mockito-Kotlin.